# Is there a way to download only certain jQuery components?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm currently developing a website, where performance is crucial — and after testing the speed, I found that jQuery takes a long time to load, which isn't too good, since I only use the `$.post` and `$.get` functions out of the many others jQuery offers.

Is there any way to only download a version of jQuery that only uses these two functions?

I've tried searching for any solution, but I only found [outdated answers from over 11 years ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1665010/jquery-how-to-download-only-necessary-components) or [solutions that aren't entirely cross browser compatible](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API).

Comment: Change to fetch.

Comment: You don't need jquery for get and post only at all then, use JS native API Fetch https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch

Comment: HTTP request functionality is built natively into every browser, you don't need jQuery for that. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest

Comment: jQuery actually removed ajax and effects from their "slim builds" because browsers provide more standard, built in alternate (fetch api, css animatione etc).

Comment: [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API)

Comment: After a little google-fu: http://projects.jga.me/jquery-builder/

Comment: http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/#post